# Efficiently merging lists based on a merge criteria

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, merge

I have three sorted lists that I want to merge into one in a particular order derived from a comma-separated string. The three lists look like below:

```
List<Square> squares;
List<Ball> balls;
List<Triangle> triangles;
```

Now I want to merge all these lists into the shapes list where Shape is the parent class to adding to this list does not break anything.

```
List<Shape> shapes
```

Each list is sorted by an id on each list type object. The merge order is based on the order provided by this string (I am open to a better representation as this is super hacky):

```
String mergeOrder = "Ball, Triangle, Squares"
```

Based on the above merge order, I want to take one shape from each list in the order above and add to the shapes list until one of the lists runs out of objects. At this point, the merge order should continue with the remaining lists. ie:

```
Balls List:
12
16
20

Triangles List:
1

Squares List:
9
10

Merged List:
12 -> Ball
1 -> Triangle
9 -> Square
16 -> Ball
10 -> Square (Triangles ran out)
20 -> Ball (Squares ran out)
```

Whats the best way to do this type of merge process? Any code snippets/skeletons would greatly help!

Comment: I suggest `List<List<Shape>> mergeOrder = Arrays.asList(balls, triangles, squares)` instead of that string. The code will also follow somewhat naturally from there: just iterate through the list repeatedly, popping elements off as you go. `list.remove(0)` is a simple way to go, although unless the lists are `LinkedList`s (which is usually not a good idea, even here) it will notably more efficient (if they're long, otherwise don't bother) to reverse the lists first. Make a copy using `new ArrayList<>(list)` first if you don't want to modify the originals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code

```
public class Main {

   private static class Shape {

      private final String value;

      private final String type;

      public Shape(String type, String value) {
         this.type = type;
         this.value = value;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return type + "[" + value + "]";
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Shape> balls = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Shape> triangles = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Shape> squares = new ArrayList<>();
      balls.add(new Shape("Ball", "10"));
      balls.add(new Shape("Ball", "12"));
      balls.add(new Shape("Ball", "16"));
      triangles.add(new Shape("Triangle", "1"));
      squares.add(new Shape("Square", "4"));
      squares.add(new Shape("Square", "5"));

      List<Iterator<Shape>> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
      shapes.add(balls.iterator());
      shapes.add(triangles.iterator());
      shapes.add(squares.iterator());

      List<Shape> merged = new ArrayList<>();

      boolean finished = false;
      while (!finished) {
         boolean hasNext = false;
         for (Iterator<Shape> iterator : shapes) {
            hasNext = hasNext || iterator.hasNext();
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
               merged.add(iterator.next());
            }
         }
         finished = !hasNext;
      }

      System.out.println(merged);

   }
}
```

UPDATE:

Iteration with streams:

```
  boolean finished = false;
  while (!finished) {
     List<Iterator<Shape>> iteratorsWithNext = shapes.stream().filter(
           s -> s.hasNext()).collect(Collectors.toList());
     iteratorsWithNext.forEach(it -> merged.add(it.next()));
     finished = iteratorsWithNext.isEmpty();
  }
```

The output

```
[Ball[10], Triangle[1], Square[4], Ball[12], Square[5], Ball[16]]
```

Comment: Is there any way to simplify the logic here using Java8 streams?